# Youtube API v3, How to get Top Artists for each country

Tags: android, ios, youtube

I am using Youtube API V3 to fetch current top trends from youtube API for my Android and iOS app.
I want to show Top Artists for each country.
Any idea how can I retrieve the list of top Artists from Youtube API.
located [here](https://www.youtube.com/yt/artists/charts.html).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use below api to get list 
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=contentDetails&chart=mostPopular&regionCode=IN&maxResults=25&key=AIz.............

Pass region code in regionCode parameter .
pass your api key generated in   key parameter

You can get region code from Telephony manger or from locale . I hope this gives you a understanding that how you can proceed